# I want to downgrade from Yosemite 10.10 to Mavericks or previous operating system

Tags: macos

I want to downgrade from Yosemite 10.10 to previous operating system (i think its name was Mavericks).

I am not experienced in Computers so please explain to me in simple, step by step way.

Why i want to go back to Mavericks?

After installing Yosemite:
- My Mac is always very hot;
- The Fan is working as soon as it starts;
- Battery is getting half its normal time.
- Most important, the computer hangs a lot and became very slow.

With all this probe, I feel i am not using an apple computer any more..

Thanks to anyone who can assist.

Comment: I agree that Yosemite has a distinctly non-Apple feel about it ... it feels like some ugly corporate bland product that you might expect from Microsoft or Google. I have kicked it off my computer, and re-installed Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent Time Machine backup from before you upgraded, you can restore the backup and you will be back on Mavericks. You will lose any new files, changes, etc. that have been made since you upgraded to Yosemite, unless you back these up **before** you attempt to downgrade.

Follow these steps, from [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/22/downgrade-os-x-yosemite-to-mavericks/):

> 1. Reboot the Mac with Yosemite and hold down Command+R to enter Recovery mode (You can also hold Option and choose “Recovery HD”, or if you have a Yosemite USB installer key, you can boot from that too)
> 2. At the OS X Utilities menu, choose “Restore From Time Machine Backup”
> 3. Connect the Time Machine drive that contains the most recent Mavericks backup to the Mac (typically through USB or Thunderbolt), then click “Continue”
> 4. At the “Select a Backup Source” screen, choose the Time Machine volume used for the Mavericks backup and click Continue
> 5. Under “Backup Date & Time”, select the most recent backup made from OS X Mavericks – double-check the OS X Version menu to make sure it’s “10.9.5” (or whatever 10.9.x you had previously), then click Continue again
> 6. Choose the Destination drive (the Yosemite volume you want to downgrade) to restore the OS X Mavericks backup to – this will erase OS X Yosemite and revert back to Mavericks on that drive, be sure you backed up all files created between the most recent backup date and now or you will lose them – click on “Restore” to begin the downgrade process
>
> ...
>
> The downgrade process can take quite a while depending on the size of the backup, the amount of files on the drive, the speed of the Mac, and the speed of the hard drive. Expect this process to take several hours if not many hours, for a very large hard drive of stuff, it could easily take overnight if not a full day to complete hundreds of GB of file transfers. Do not interrupt the restore process, otherwise you would need to start over.

Answer (score 0):

I think Yosemite is the ugliest Mac OS that Apple has ever released (and I have been there since the beginning). I think the look-and-feel is appalling, and I cannot stomach it ... so have reverted to Mavericks.

If you do not have a Time Machine backup, then there are two main options:

**1. Command-R:  Recovery system**

If you have a newer Mac, when you boot up your Mac, hold down Command-R ... this allows you to install a new copy of OS X Mavericks which it will download from the Apple servers on the internet.

Downside:  it does not let you install Mavericks when you have Yosemite already installed, so you need to Erase your HD using Disk utility (make a backup first, of course), and then re-boot your Mac, hold down Command-R, and install a fresh system - you end up with a brand new Mac.

For more detail, see:  http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718

**2.  Bootable Mavericks USB stick**

In theory, if you have Mavericks installed as a bootable USB stick, you should be able to install Mavericks from that. It didn't actually work for me, perhaps because my version of Mavericks on the USB stick (Jan 2014) came out before the date I purchased my Macbook Air ... and I had to use the recovery system which worked fine ... albeit starting clean from fresh.

For help creating a bootable Mavericks install USB stick:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/

There is also an article in Macworld on how to revert to Mavericks from Yosemite:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/revert-back-mavericks-from-yosemite-3581872/